What's the best way to get your firebase-admin project's projectId since the move to GoogleAuth in 13.x
There were a few ways you were able to get a project's projectId, pre 13.x, App.options.projectId, or casting a credential to a ServiceAccount, and ServiceAccount.projectId.
Since the move to 13.x, it seems like all projectId's are lazily set via Promise accessors, https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Afirebase%2Ffirebase-admin-node+getprojectId&type=code and, specifically, an app's default credential, via applicationDefault() or App.options.credential is defined as a plain old Credential https://github.com/SuperStreaming/firebase-admin-node/blob/3abd40e2bcfb6b22933656c0caaf183b671f14cb/src/app/credential.ts#L39
Instead of what it actually is, an ApplicationDefaultCredential, https://github.com/SuperStreaming/firebase-admin-node/blob/3abd40e2bcfb6b22933656c0caaf183b671f14cb/src/app/credential-internal.ts#L37
Of course, I can cast the credential to
app.options.credential as any as { googleAuth: GoogleAuth }

Or follow the approach in the task docs, https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/task-functions?gen=2nd#retrieve-and
  const auth = new GoogleAuth({
    scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
  });
  const projectId = await auth.getProjectId();

But that just doesn't really make much sense to me. If you're creating the application credential, I don't understand why it's internals are then so obfuscated and hidden away, particularly when the GoogleAuth part which is a completely open class which you can create (albeit with some overhead) yourself.
When you then add in that the 2 "public" projectId fields are undefined, now only since 13.x, in
AppOptions, https://github.com/SuperStreaming/firebase-admin-node/blob/3abd40e2bcfb6b22933656c0caaf183b671f14cb/src/app/core.ts#L72 and
ServiceAccount, https://github.com/SuperStreaming/firebase-admin-node/blob/3abd40e2bcfb6b22933656c0caaf183b671f14cb/src/app/credential.ts#L19
It all makes even less sense.
